# JSON: Escape & in Java

Tags: java, json

I have issue with parsing a String which has an ampersand `&` in the String. Is there a way to escape the `&` or encode the `&` in Java?

Appreciate help!
Thanks.

Comment: try using Jackson to encode/decode objects to/from JSON. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: In JSON the character `&` does not have a special meaning. In what context do you use the generated JSON then? Maybe HTML? Then you need to encode the *whole* JSON string at this point.

Comment: I am trying to replace & with the String amp; and then again decoding it back. Is this the right way or there is some standard way to escape the & char?. I am actually new to Java please help me out.

Comment: You could use [StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) to escape the '&'

Comment: Using Jackson and  StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4 work!.. Thanks... Is there some more options for this.